# How to make express.js work properly in nuxt3

Tags: typescript, express, http, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

nuxt.config.ts:

```js
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: true,
    css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', 'mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'],
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
        // @ts-ignore
        postcss: {
            postcssOptions: {
                plugins: {
                    tailwindcss: {},
                    autoprefixer: {},
                },
            },
        },
    },
    vite: {
        define: {
            'process.env.DEBUG': false,
        },
    },
    serverMiddleware: [
        // Will register file from project server-middleware directory to handle /api/* requests
        '~/server-middleware/index.ts'
    ],

    /*css: [
        '@/assets/css/main.css',
    ],*/
});
```

index.ts file from server-middleware

```js
import express from "express";
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get( "/", ( req, res ) => {
    res.send( "Hello world!" );
} );


app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "I work" });
})

module.exports = {
    path: '/server-middleware',
    handler: app
}
```

packet structure

[image: packet structure]

When I go on my website localhost:3000 it doesn't give a response.
Also when I go to localhost:3000/test, does anyone know where the mistake is?

Comment: Can't you use that directly? https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server

Comment: Any Updates on this?  I found this article on dev.to: https://dev.to/mihaiandrei97/nuxt3-express-api-bf5